# jquery not working with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

i am trying to add input boxes on click. but its strange without [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) it is working means input boxes is generating but with [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) it is not working.

Also tested with `alert("testing");` alert is successfully coming.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div id="p_scents1">        
                        <a href="#" id="addScnt1">Add More</a>
                        <% _.each( type.size, function(i, listItem ){ %>
                                 <%= "<p><label for='p_scents1'><input id='TypeSize"+listItem+"' class='form-control' type='text' placeholder='Please enter  Type size' required='required' value='"+i+"' name='data[Type][size]["+listItem+"]'></label></p>" %>
                        <% }); %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var scntDiv = $('#p_scents1');
            var i = $('#p_scents1 p').size();

            $('#addScnt1').live('click', function() { 
           alert("testing"); //tested . alert is working fine. but append is not working.
                $(scntDiv).append('<p><label for="p_scents1"><input id="TypeSize0" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Please enter Type size" required="required" name="data[Type][size]['+i+']"></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt1">Remove</a></p>');
                i++;
                return false;
            });

            $('#remScnt1').live('click', function() {
                if( i > 1 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: use 'on' instead of live.

Comment: but live is working without underscore.js and i have tried with "on" same problem arise.

Comment: Your code will generate duplicated ids (remScnt1). You need to use class for remove button*S*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those 2 elements are dynamically building, You have to use delegate like this

```
 $(document).on('click', '#addScnt1', function () {
    var i = $('#p_scents1 p').size();         
     $(scntDiv).append('<p><label for="p_scents1"><input id="TypeSize0" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Please enter Type size" required="required" name="data[Type][size][' + i + ']"></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt1">Remove</a></p>');
     i++;
     return false;
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remScnt1', function () {
      var i = $('#p_scents1 p').size();         
      if (i > 1) {
         $(this).parents('p').remove();
         i--;
     }
     return false;
 });
```

**Edit**

Instead of appending all the elements, troubleshoot the steps by adding elements one by one. 
First you can try like this,

```
$('#p_scents1').append("<span>test</span>");
```

Then add elements and findout which element causes the problem.

Comment: _live is working without underscore.js_ OP commented this. Since OP is using jquery version 1.8 `.live()` will work, yet OP says it is not working when underscore js gets implemented.

Comment: But the implementation is different. Here it is binding the events with delegate

Comment: line Yury Tarabanko said, can you change the id to a class?

Comment: thats the second thing. first need Input box generate.

Comment: can you put an alert in it? and try

Comment: Mr. Anoop Please be in question. i have already tried all these. need more experienced help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57069/discussion-between-anoop-joshi-and-puzzled-boy).